# Report: Account field history

Tags: reporting

1)
I have created a report on the Account Field History.
I have filtered on the field `Status`.

Now I want to count the number of accounts that have gone from `New` to `Archived`.

I am not sure how I can filter on the old and new values. Any ideas?

2)
I also want to create a second report in which I count how many accounts were set to `Archived` this month. In this case I somehow need to put a filter on the New Value field and set it to `Archived` and then a filter on the last 30 days.

3)
Is there some good documentation on creating field history reports?

Tia, Lily.

Comment: From `New` to `Archived` in one step (DML event) or including intermediate steps?

Comment: That is in one step.

Comment: Hmm.  Options:  (1) `Historical Trend Reporting` is not available for `Accounts` so that won't work; (2) AccountHistory reports don't give you the filters you need.  (3) `Analytic Snapshots` frequency may miss changes; (4) Either custom VF page using SOQL in controller or something like Conga Composer where you can post process results in Excel.

Answer (score 0):

Hi @Lily For History related reports.As per i understood about your requirements.

You have to select report type:account History

And you put a filter and select Field/Event Equals Your field.

For reference:[image]

2.You can filter your results with your conditions.But It shows changes from old value to new value

3.If you want retrieve a particular month report use respected date field criteria as per your requirement and select like this month

May be it works for you.If you face any issues let me know.

Comment: Pavan -- OP has a tricky problem -- Account may have changed from New to Foo to Bar to Archived over 4 different dates. Elaborate on how this answer counts Accounts that were in New at start of date range and then were in Archived at end of date range?

Comment: Hello. That's exactly my problem. I need to create a report that only shows reports that have gone directly from New to Archived. It looks like it's not possible to do that.

Comment: Hey thanks @cropredy how i forgot that.In case my case only owner changes from with single user it works perfectly.Because we can't filter old value & new value in that report.Even i tried so many things didn't work.